# Why does ephemeris file need for gps spoofing? Is it possible to generate ephemeris on the fly if fake satellite is near to gps receiver?

Tags: gps, spoofing

There are tools on github like gps-sdr-sim and others that allow to generate simulated range data is then used to create the digitized I/Q samples for the GPS signal for hackrf, limesdr, bladerf etc. The simulation start time can be specified if the corresponding set of ephemerides is available. Ephemeris for current day, week is available on Nasa website.
Is it possible to generate ephemeris data for static transmitter (fake satellite) which is on the ground? Will gps receiver fix its coordinates?